# remove last character from a string inside a loop in php

Tags: php, string, for-loop

i am trying to check whether VIN number is valid or not using PHP. I am using for loop as shown below

```
 $base='**********';
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
    $query_string .= "$key=" . urlencode($value) . "&";
    }
$url = "$base?$query_string";
```

in this iam getting **`&`** as last charecter like below

```
&reportType=3&
```

i tried to remove this using below code but its not working

```
substr($query_string, 0, -1);
 mb_substr($query_string, 0, -1);
```

Help me for remove last charecter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to assign the result back to your variable.

```
$query_string = substr($query_string, 0, -1);
```

Comment: does this not get the & char only?

Comment: @ozkanozlu no, check the docs. straight from there [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: It will remove whatever's at the end, just like your original was supposed to.

Comment: Yeah, and now everybody's changed their answers to include the assignment. How am I the only one that caught that? :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

```
$trimmed = rtrim($query_string, "&")
```

will remove any `&` from the end.

Your code works too, but you need to assign it to a variable since it returns a new string. Same with rtrim, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$base='index.php';
$params = array("key1"=>1,"key2"=>2,"key3"=>3,"key4"=>4);
$size = count($params);
$count = 1;
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
    $query_string .= "$key=" . urlencode($value);
    if($count < $size){
      $query_string .= "&";
    }
    $count++;
    }
$url = "$base?$query_string";
echo $url;
```

//Result: index.php?key1=1&key2=2&key3=3&key4=4